# Escape eval command when appending to file

Tags: bash

I am trying to append append the following string to a file using bash

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

when ever i try this it executes the eval command, i have tried the following variations to escape the eval text

```
'eval' "$(rbenv init -)"
"eval" "$(rbenv init -)"
`eval` "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: You want to append the literal text `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to a file? Single quote the whole thing. `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> file`.

Comment: thanks put as answer if you want :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your attempts have `$()` inside double quotes.  It needs to be inside single quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting it when you echo it:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> file
```

Comment: needs to be in double quotes since it will be interpreted by shell, on login. Etans answer was correct

Comment: Right, I've clarified my answer (by copying from @EtanReisner, who hasn't posted his own answer so far).